# Reading a formatted data file in Fortran 90

Tags: fortran, fortran90, ioerror

I have a file to read whose structure is:

```
26.0  24773  -55.4  -86.8 1   0.01 60 27  617.7  617.8  617.
24.2  25230  -55.7  -86.7 1   0.01 64 22  629.7  629.8  629.
```

#### Station information and sounding indices

I'm interested in reading only the number. I used the following format:

```
read(333,10) a(i),b(i)...
10 format(1x,f6.1,2x,i5,...
read(333,iostat=stat) Station

if(stat/=0)then
else
endif

if(stat==0)exit
```

from this the error appears:

```
forrtl: severe (64): input conversion error, unit 333, file
```

Comment: It is necessary to show the full `read` and `format` statements and indicate, if there are any columns with space characters before the first number in the text file.

Comment: you  dont need an explicit format. do `read(333,*)`

Comment: note also every read needs some sort of format, explicit or list directed ("*") , so your second read is broken.